# Update list item periodically using stream with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm writing an app that communicates with a server. The app will have a listview with items inside that need to be updated periodically (every x seconds) and I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

Let's say I have a Stream that sends a request to a server every 5 seconds. I yield the result, but how can I receive this data inside of a view and update it?

for example:

Stream:

```
Stream<double> progress(int id) async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    double progress = await api.getProgressFor(id: id);
    yield progress;
  }
}
```

How could I create a widget, say a `LinearProgressIndicator` that will listen for yields from this stream and update when they are sent.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, one of which is to try the `StreamBuilder` widget.

Comment: Thank you @user1032613 that's exactly the direction I needed to be sent in.

Comment: another option is to use a ChangeNotifier https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier

Comment: I had a similar problem and used a MultiProvider at the top level of my app with several ChangeNotifiers as data controllers. Makes it much easier to share and access data throughout the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `StreamBuilder`. Here is a sample showing where you call your stream and where you display your ListView or similar.

```
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder <int>(
      stream: callProgressStream , 
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return  CircularProgressIndicator();
        else {
          // Your code here
          return ListView();}
      });
  }
```

Let me know if this does not help.